# What is a property and a control in Pega 7.2?

Tags: pega

I want to know the difference between controls and properties in **PEGA 7.2**.

Comment: do you have knowledge on c or c++ or java? if you have i will take example and explain.

Answer (score 3):

Property is like a variable in Java - 
https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v72/procomhelpmain.htm#rule-/rule-obj-/rule-obj-property/main.htm?Highlight=properties

Controls are used in pega to define how properties appear on UI - 
https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v72/procomhelpmain.htm#rule-/rule-html-/rule-html-property/main.htm

PDN is best source for all pega related definitions

Comment: I like this answer. concise and with links to the official documentation. It could be improve by means of some formatting, but overall good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Property is a Data field in general. You can imagine a variable in C or Java. That can be primitive type or complex type. In Pega, property type may be Single or Page, Page List, Object...etc.

Control is a UI component like textbox, button, checkbox, link...etc.

A property can be associated with a control to display in certain format on a user screen.

I would define a property 'CustomerName' and my control to read Customer name is 'TextBox'.

Answer (score 0):

A property stores some value. It is like a box.

Control is a user interface element, which helps your system to get a value from or show it to a customer.

Always, properties and control are used together.
For example, a user fulfills a UI control with theirs name. And the name is assigned to some property.